# Editar Dado PHP com Jquery e Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Senhores, porque no código abaixo não está passando os dados (fetch) para o modal para que eu possa atualizar?

**Html**

```
<a href="#editModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">&#xE254;</i></a><input type="hidden" name="update_id" id="update_id">                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Título</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Nome do lead" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Telefone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>E-mail</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Valor</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value" id="value" required>
                    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
// Edit modal
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'edit', function(){

        $('#editModal').modal('show');

            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();

            console.log(data);

            $('#update_id').val(data[0]);
            $('#title').val(data[1]);
            $('#phone').val(data[2]);
            $('#email').val(data[3]);
            $('#value').val(data[4]);
            $('#step').val(data[5]);
            $('#prob').val(data[6]);
    });
});
```

Comment: `.on('click', 'edit', ...` não deveria ser `.on('click', '.edit', ...`, com o ponto antes de `edit` sinalizando que é uma classe CSS?

Comment: @Woss, não amigo.

Comment: Deveria sim. O segundo argumento ali é o seletor. Pode ser que não seja só esse o problema, mas que isso está errado está.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#editModal").on('show.bs.modal', event => {
        tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        let data =[];

        $(tr).find('td').each (function() {
            data.push(this.html());
        });  

        $('#update_id').val(data[0]);
        $('#title').val(data[1]);
        $('#phone').val(data[2]);
        $('#email').val(data[3]);
        $('#value').val(data[4]);
        $('#step').val(data[5]);
        $('#prob').val(data[6]);
    });
```